# Is there a tool to statically analyse python code to determine if mutable parameters are changes (detect side effects)

Tags: python, functional-programming

Is there a Python static analysis tool which can detect when function parameters are mutated, therefore causing a side-effect?

```
that is
def foo(x):
    x.append("x at the end")
```

will change the calling scope x when x is a list.

Can this reliably be detected? I'm asking because such a tool would make it easier to comply with pure functional approaches.

I suppose a decorator could be used to warn about it (for development) but this wouldn't be as reliable as static analysis.

Comment: Given that it's impossible to know which methods or operators mutate `x` without even knowing the type of `x`, much less how that type is defined (and that may even be in C), there can't possibly be a tool that does everything you're asking.

Comment: A better solution would be to use static _type_ checks. If `foo` is defined to take a `list`, or a `MutableSequence`, then you know it intends to mutate `x`; if it's defined to take a `Sequence`, then the type checker is going to fail the `x.append` call, because `Sequence` has no such method. There are a variety of static type checkers out there, but not much standardization between them. Guido wants to change that for 3.5 or 3.6, and he likes [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/) as a starting point, so you might want to look there first.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at mypy. Presumably if a class, like FrozenDict, does not offer in-place mutating functions, MyPy can statically 'enforce' this and that is probably the best we can expect.

Comment: Exactly. That's basically the solution people use in typed functional programming. And really, this is exactly the kind of thing that static type systems are _for_. (If you were looking for a magic "make an immutable type out of this mutable type" modifier like C++'s or D's `const`—together with all the problems `const` entails—then Python doesn't have that, any more than, e.g., any typed Scheme, or ML derivative, etc. does.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foo` function will mutate its argument if it's called with a `list`—but if it's called with something different, it might raise an exception, or do something that doesn't mutate it.

Similarly, you can write a type that mutates itself every time you call `len` on it, and then a function that just printing the length of its argument would be mutating its arguments.

It's even worse if you use an operator like `+=`, which will call the (generally-mutating) `__iadd__` method on types that have it, like `list`, but will call the (non-mutating) `__add__` method on types that don't, like `tuple`. So, what are you going to do in those cases?

For that matter, even a `for` loop over an argument is mutating if you pass in an iterator, but (usually) not if you pass in a sequence.

If you just want to make a list of frequently-mutating method names and operators and search for those, that wouldn't be too hard to write as an AST visitor. But that's going to give you a lot of both false negatives and false positives.

---

This is exactly the kind of problem that static typing was designed to solve. Python doesn't have static typing built it, but it's possible to build on top of Python.

First, if you're using Python 3.x, you can use annotations to store the types of the parameters. For example:

```
def foo(x: MutableSequence) -> NoneType:
    x.append("x at the end")
```

Now you know, from the fact that it takes a `MutableSequence` (or a `list`) rather than a `Sequence`, that it *intends* to mutate its parameter. And, even if it doesn't do so now, some future version might well do so, so you should trust its annotations anyway.

And now you can solve your problem the same way you would in Haskell or ML: your pure functional code takes a `Sequence` and it calls functions with that `Sequence`, and you just need to ensure that none of those functions is defined to take a `MutableSequence`, right?

That last part is the hard part. Python doesn't stop me from writing this:

```
def foo(x: Sequence) -> NoneType:
    x.append("x at the end")
```

For that, you need a static type checker. Guido has been pushing to standardize annotations to allow the [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/) static checker to become a semi-official part of Python. It's not completely finished yet, and it's not as powerful a type system as typical typed functional languages, but it will handle most Python code well enough for what you're looking for. But mypy isn't the only static type checker available; there are others if you search.

Anyway, with a type checker, that `foo` function would fail with an error explaining that `Sequence` has no such method `append`. And if, on the other hand, `foo` were properly defined as taking a `MutableSequence`, your functional code that calls it with a `Sequence` would fail with an error explaining that `Sequence` is not a subtype of `MutableSequence`.

Comment: Would a static type checker prevent me from doing (in your foo function that takes a sequence): x[2].frobnicate()? (where this method changes the state of the 2nd element of x)  Would you consider a static type checker for Python *reliable*?

Comment: @Gerrat: That depends on how powerful the type system is. Mypy handles simple (Java-like) generics, so you can `def foo(x: Sequence[Spam])`, and if `Spam` is an immutable object without a `frobnicate` method, you'll get an error. (The key here is that it's easier to check for immutable types, than to check for mutable types being used immutably. So you may need to define an immutable `Spam` and mutable subtype `FrobinatableSpam`—just like `Sequence` and `MutableSequence`.)

Comment: @Gerrat: Anyway, if by "reliable" you mean "no false positives unless you've forgotten to type something properly": that's actually a big issue. Some type checkers allow only what they can prove is legal, others only what they can't prove is illegal. The big issue there is when you mix typed and untyped code. A strict checker will assume anything that's passed through an un-annotated function is basically `object` and has no methods unless you explicitly "downcast" it somewhere; a lenient checker will assume it's a magic type with all methods. Which you want depends on your program.

Comment: Interesting.  Given the dynamic nature of Python and that you can change pretty much anything at runtime, there's probably about a dozen or more built-ins, which, if they appear anywhere in your program would nullify any guarantees about what any function anywhere did (eg. eval, locals, dir(), etc).  I wonder what the static type checkers do when one of these is present.

Comment: @Gerrat: `dir` isn't going to do anything dangerous, and `locals` explicitly documents that any changes you make may not affect the actual local or closure variables, so it's mainly just `eval` and `exec`. Anyway, the "right" answer seems to be that after `exec` all local variables become undeclared (so they're either `object` or `duck`, depending on whether your checker is strict or loose). But I could imagine a strict checker deciding to ignore `exec` under a "consenting adults" rule.

Comment: @Gerrat: A bigger issue is that many Python function types are pretty hard to annotate. For example, `map` takes `(T1, T2, …)->U,  Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2], …` and returns `Iterator[U]`. How do you specify those `...` parts? You could try to write overloads for 1, 2, …, N arguments and beyond that raise an error. Or you could come up with a language that allows you to generate the schema recursively or iteratively. Or you could do what mypy does and just punt on it and `map` with 2 or more iterables implicitly collapses everything to `duck`.